# Google Foobar Bug chahallenge resets after submit

Tags: java, python, google-chrome

Im on Level 2, part 2: (Level 2, 50%)

After I submitted challenge (java) I got nothing - the time stops and status doesn't update.
Logout/Clear cash - doesn't work, all looks like I need request the new challenge but I did it twice! And it doesn't work at all!

I posted bug though Feedback command from foo.bar but who knows where it goes.

Who knows where I can find foo.bar bug tracker? To understand what is going on.
Also I will appreciate any help and advice.
Thanks!

google-chrome, macos, foobar version 53-17-g6bfce4dd-beta (2017-03-21-22:12+0000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of waiting for any messages from support or new build I have decided to request a new challenge (3rd one) and vuala - the system accepted my solution and promoted me to the 3rd level.